# How to unselect feature after selecting all

Tags: javascript, gis, openlayers-3

I have a map with a vector layer with some features.

```
var map = new ol.Map({
  view: mapManager.zoomedView(),
  target: 'map-business',
  layers: [
    new ol.layer.Tile({
      source: new ol.source.OSM()
    })
  ]
})
var vectorSource = new ol.source.Vector();

var feats;
$.get( "/test.geojson", function( data ) {
  vectorSource.addFeatures(new ol.format.GeoJSON().readFeatures(data))
  feats = new ol.format.GeoJSON().readFeatures(data)
});
var vectorLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({
  source: vectorSource,
  style: new ol.style.Style({
    fill: mapManager.defaultFill(),
    stroke: mapManager.defaultStroke()
  })
});

map.addLayer(vectorLayer);
```

Then I add a select interaction because I want to unselect/select features

```
var selectSingleClick = new ol.interaction.Select({
  condition: ol.events.condition.click,
  toggleCondition: ol.events.condition.click,
  style: new ol.style.Style({
    fill: mapManager.selectFill(),
    stroke: mapManager.selectStroke()
  })
});

map.addInteraction(selectSingleClick);
```

Now I want to select all features by default

```
var selectableFeatures = selectSingleClick.getFeatures()
selectableFeatures.push(feats[i])
```

It is ok, all my features are selected by default. Problem is that I can not unselect my features. If I click on a feature, the feature is selected again.

Comment: How about each time truncate your selectableFeatures before doing a selection?

Comment: @TengMa But should I use ol.interaction.Select?

Comment: Any feedback ...?

Comment: @JonatasWalker yes sorry I am in a rush to finish my project. Feedback during the next week ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like:

```
var vectorSource = new ol.source.Vector({
  format: new ol.format.GeoJSON,
  url: '/test.geojson'
});

var vectorLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({
  source: vectorSource,
  // ...
});

map.addLayer(vectorLayer);

var featuresInteraction = new ol.Collection();
var selectSingleClick = new ol.interaction.Select({
  features: featuresInteraction, // <-- pushing and removing from/to this collection variable
  // ...
});
map.addInteraction(selectSingleClick);

// GeoJSON was async loaded, so wait until is ready
vectorSource.once('addfeature', function(evt) {
  // add to select collection
  featuresInteraction.extend(vectorSource.getFeatures());

  // some time later to remove selected
  window.setTimeout(function() {
    featuresInteraction.clear();
  }, 2000);
});
```

Comment: With this solution I can not unselect features individually. Actually this is what I try to do. With your answer I can only unselect all features isn'it?